# Can you target a specific DOM element by executing an event on it?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to target an element in the DOM as I would with getElementById(), but solely by clicking on it. For example, I want to turn the following div from red to green (below is the standard way):

```
function changeColor(element, value)
{
    document.getElementById(element).style.background = value;
}

<div id="square"  style="height: 100px; width: 100px; 
background:red;" onClick="changeColor('square', 'green');"></div>
```

...but I want to do something like this:

```
function changeColor(THIS, value)
{
    THIS('element receiving the click').style.background = value;
}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

In your code you can use `document.getElementById`:

```
function changeColor(id, value) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = value;
}
```

But a better way is to use `this` in the function call, as it's automatically set to the element that was clicked on.

```
onclick="changeColor(this, 'green')"
```

Then the function will receive the element as an argument:

```
function changeColor(element, value) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = value;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but then can I use the event to affect parents and children as well with this same method?

Comment: Just a guess: maybe @Argut wants a very generic solution like add event handler to body or whatever parent and then catch `event.target.style`?

Comment: It would be even better to separate out the JS from the HTML and add an event listener to the element.

Comment: The reason for my question is, I have a bunch of <div>s that contain blog posts fetched from a DB. Each one has an "edit" button that I would like to apply an "onclick" function to . If I target these by id, all these attributes need to be unique. That isn't possible however, as each <div> with its respective post and edit button are being generated automatically as the html structure around the fetched DB data, so they will not have unique attributes. I need something that targets the sibling/parent elements of only to the button I'm clicking on.

Comment: @Axel do you want to use the event delegation?? And Andy yes is better separate out js from the html

Comment: @Argust you can asign a class to the elements and use a loop to iterate over those elements, you can use for, forEach, map etc

Comment: @Argut if you show us the actual markup we can show you how to targt these elements without ugly onclick stuff...

Comment: @Argut You can use things like `element.children` and `element.parentNode` to do things to the children and parents as well. It gets even easier if you can use jQuery, it has very compact syntax for this so you don't have to write loops.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for your help!! Much appreciated.